# Ionic 2: How to handle the hardware back button which checks confirmation of Exit in app

Tags: android, angular, ionic2

I am facing an issue how to handle the default mobile's back button which checks the confirmation while exiting from the application, if I pressed the back button there should invoke some handler which shows pop-up, for confirm exiting.
OR there is any method call registerBackButtonAction()? or is it so how to use it in **IONIC 2**,?
Please help me out. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is my resolved and working Code. Thank you everyone.

```
constructor(platform: Platform,public alertCtrl: AlertController,public toastCtrl:ToastController) {
    platform.ready().then(()=>{
       platform.registerBackButtonAction(()=>this.myHandlerFunction());
       StatusBar.styleDefault();
      Splashscreen.hide();
})
  }

    myHandlerFunction(){
     let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
      message: "Press Again to Confirm Exit",
      duration: 3000
    });
    toast.present(); 
     }
```

Answer (score 26):

In app.component.ts

```
        @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

        constructor(private platform: Platform, private toastCtrl:   ToastController, private alertCtrl: AlertController) {
            platform.ready().then(() => {
              // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
              // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need

              platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {


                //uncomment this and comment code below to to show toast and exit app
                // if (this.backButtonPressedOnceToExit) {
                //   this.platform.exitApp();
                // } else if (this.nav.canGoBack()) {
                //   this.nav.pop({});
                // } else {
                //   this.showToast();
                //   this.backButtonPressedOnceToExit = true;
                //   setTimeout(() => {

                //     this.backButtonPressedOnceToExit = false;
                //   },2000)
                // }

                if(this.nav.canGoBack()){
                  this.nav.pop();
                }else{
                  if(this.alert){ 
                    this.alert.dismiss();
                    this.alert =null;     
                  }else{
                    this.showAlert();
                   }
                }
              });
            });

          }

          showAlert() {
          this.alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
            title: 'Exit?',
            message: 'Do you want to exit the app?',
            buttons: [
              {
                text: 'Cancel',
                role: 'cancel',
                handler: () => {
                  this.alert =null;
                }
              },
              {
                text: 'Exit',
                handler: () => {
                  this.platform.exitApp();
                }
              }
            ]
          });
          alert.present();
        }

          showToast() {
            let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
              message: 'Press Again to exit',
              duration: 2000,
              position: 'bottom'
            });

            toast.onDidDismiss(() => {
              console.log('Dismissed toast');
            });

            toast.present();
          }
```

Comment: Hello Sir,
I have followed your lead on exiting the app on hardware back button and it's working like a charm. But the app goes to the background mode and I want to kill the app instead of the previous situation. And the alertCtrl is fired over and over again when I press the hardware button multiple times(Isn't the alertctrl be fired only once and should be disabled afterwards, if there is any way to do that, I'll be glad to have your help on it).Thank you :)

Comment: @AnkushThakur I have made some changes to the code for tackling multiple alerts. Please check it out.

Comment: @AnkushThakur this.platform.exitApp()  is working for exiting the app succesfully for me. Maybe you are missing this <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" /> in your config file.

Comment: Where does this.nav come from ?

Comment: where is this this.nav coming from?

Comment: @nabin: this solution doesn't always work when a page is pushed from inside one of the pages in tabs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46757910/handling-android-back-button-in-ionic-3-with-tabs

Comment: @Ari I have not tried it but  https://stackoverflow.com/a/41373775/2538207 should be of help

Comment: this.alert.present();

Comment: I used the same method and it works fine but it has one drawback, if you have any ModalController opened then tapping the hardware back button on Android takes the nav controller to back while still keeping the Modal on top of the existing navigation.

Comment: how to define  var alert  here. like a string ?

Answer (score 16):

Ionic latest version 3.xx

`app.component.ts` file:

```
import { Platform, Nav, Config, ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(public toastCtrl: ToastController, public platform: Platform) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
        //back button handle
        //Registration of push in Android and Windows Phone
        var lastTimeBackPress = 0;
        var timePeriodToExit  = 2000;

        platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
            // get current active page
            let view = this.nav.getActive();
            if (view.component.name == "TabsPage") {
                //Double check to exit app
                if (new Date().getTime() - lastTimeBackPress < timePeriodToExit) {
                    this.platform.exitApp(); //Exit from app
                } else {
                    let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
                        message:  'Press back again to exit App?',
                        duration: 3000,
                        position: 'bottom'
                    });
                    toast.present();
                    lastTimeBackPress = new Date().getTime();
                }
            } else {
                // go to previous page
                this.nav.pop({});
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain me about this.nav and how to use NavController in app.component.ts

Comment: this solution doesn't always work when a page is pushed from inside one of the pages in tabs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46757910/handling-android-back-button-in-ionic-3-with-tabs

Comment: thanks for the answer i have scenario were i have side menu is also preset becauce of the when i go to home page(tabs page) to some other page using sidemenu my this.nav.getActive(); is showing the child page it is showing only home page as active page any idea to do pop instead of showing the toast on the second page.

Answer (score 4):

[Platform api](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/platform/Platform/#registerBackButtonAction) has a handler `registerBackButtonAction`.

You can do something like:

In app.component.ts

```
    constructor(platform: Platform){
     platform.ready().then(()=>{
       platform.registerBackButtonAction(()=>this.myHandlerFunction());
})


  myHandlerFunction(){
    //create alert
     }
```

Comment: Thank You so much suraj. Its working for me. Works like a charm for me

Comment: Only one change in code is that **this.myHandlerFunction()** and **ready() is function**

Comment: how we kill app

Answer (score 1):

Html:

```
<button (click)="exitApp()">Close application<button>
```

TypeScript:

```
import {Platform} from 'ionic-angular';

@Page({ /*...*/ })
export MyPage {
 constructor(platform: Platform) {
  this.platform = platform;
 }
 exitApp(){
  this.platform.exitApp();
 }
}
```

Comment: I dont think this is what OP is asking about.. The question is about a handler for hardware back button

Comment: Thank you Ramandeep Kaur for your help, but I want on mobile hardware back button.

Answer (score 1):

Kinda late to the party... But there is more to back button other than closing the pushed pages, specially for project with several tab pages.

Sometimes a page is pushed NOT into the root page, but in one of the  tab page's navCtrl. So we have to check for all of them.

Also, if no page or menu is open, we should circle around the most recently used tabs (similar to Instagram app) and go back to the previous tab. Moreover, we should not go back to each tab more than once (similar to Instagram)

I got inspired by the answers here and created a comprehensive method that handles all necessary features:

- **Side menu**: Closes the side menu if it was open
- **Pushed pages**: Closes any pages that might have
  been pushed on any of the tab pages’ nav controller
- **Switch between tabs**: If the menu was closed, and there was no pushed page, it should take the user back to the previous recently used tab using a stack.
- **Show alert**: If there was no previous recently used tab, an alert box should ask the user if they want to exit.

The details are in this [blog post](https://medium.com/@ourarash/handling-android-back-button-in-ionic-33f7cfbba4b9)

A demo code can be downloaded from [my github](https://github.com/ourarash/ionic3-android-back-button).

Answer (score 1):

I managed to create this function by doing a lot of research. Hope it helps.

```
    // I am using this.isExitAlertOpen just to make sure that the alert does not open if already open.

    handleBackButton() {
    this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
        // const activePortal =
        // this.ionicApp._modalPortal.getActive() ||
        // this.ionicApp._loadingPortal.getActive() ||
        // this.ionicApp._toastPortal.getActive() ||
        // this.ionicApp._overlayPortal.getActive();

        // console.warn('ACTIVE PORTALS', activePortal);

        const activeModal = this.ionicApp._modalPortal.getActive();
        console.warn('MODAL', activeModal);
```

**activePortal can be used to find the relevant active portals which includes alert, loader, modal, etc. If  you want to handle everything with the back button or some of them uncomment according to your usage**

In my case I only wanted to check if modal was active so I checked only for modal.

```
        //  if (activePortal) {
        //    activePortal.dismiss();
        //  }

        if (activeModal) {
            activeModal.dismiss();
        } else if (this.nav.canGoBack()) {
            this.nav.pop();
        } else {
            if (this.isExitAlertOpen) return;
            this.isExitAlertOpen = true;
            this.showExitAlert();
        }
    });
}

showExitAlert() {
    this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'Exit',
        message: 'Are you sure you want to exit the app?',
        enableBackdropDismiss: false,
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'Yes',
                handler: () => {
                    this.isExitAlertOpen = false;
                    this.platform.exitApp();
                }
            }, {
                text: 'Cancel',
                role: 'cancel',
                handler: () => {
                    this.isExitAlertOpen = false;
                }
            }
        ]
    }).present();
}
```