# Handling back button in Ionic 3 with tabs

Tags: android, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

This [question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42151944/ionic-2-how-to-handle-the-hardware-back-button-which-checks-confirmation-of-exit) **(copied below)** provide a solution for handling the back button in Ionic, but that solution only works when other pages are pushed directly from `app.component`, in which case calling `canGoBack` and `getActive()` on `this.nav` works correctly because other pages have been pushed using `this.nav.push` in `app.component`.

However if a page is pushed from one of the pages in the tabs (lets call it `page1`), i.e. by calling `this.navCtrl.push()` in `page1`, then `this.nav.canGoBack()` in `app.components` still resolves to false because the push happened using the `page1's` `this.navCtrl.push()` not app.component's `this.nav.push()`.

How can I detect inside `app.components` if a page was pushed from any of pages in the tabs?

```
 platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {

        if(this.nav.canGoBack()){
          this.nav.pop();
        }else{
          if(this.alert){ 
            this.alert.dismiss();
            this.alert =null;     
          }else{
            this.showAlert();
           }
        }
      });
    });

  }
```

Comment: Maybe you should store main nav in service and push page by that nav.

Comment: can you even inject NavController into app.component.ts?  can you explain why you need to detect it here?

Comment: @PhilipBrack: no, I can't, and I didn't say that. Assume each tab itself is a separate page that has `navCtrl`. On each of these pages you can call `navCtrl.push`, which I don't know how to detect in app.components. I ended up saving them in a service.

Comment: @Ari Have you handled the issue? Could you answer the problem now?

Comment: @NaveenKumarV It was long time ago, but I summarized the solution here. Hope it still works for you: https://medium.com/hackernoon/handling-android-back-button-in-ionic-33f7cfbba4b9