# registerBackButtonAction , Ionic2 , for different pages

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am developing an Ionic2 app. I am confused with `registerBackButtonAction` functionality.

I have done this on one page (say pageA). and it is working as expected.

```
this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
     console.log("back presed");
    this.abortDownloadAndExit();
    });
```

Now I want to do some other action on `registerBackButtonAction` on some other page (sayPageB). But Ionic is taking action from **pageA**

How can I register different acition on different pages.

Comment: Obvious question...did you try adding a different callback in page B?

Comment: Yes, but page B callback not work, only pageA callback works

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41373775/4826457

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 15):

As you can see in [Ionic docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/platform/Platform/#registerBackButtonAction) `registerBackButtonAction` returns a function:

> A function that, when called, will unregister its back button action. So you can use that function to restore the default behavior when leaving the page, like this:

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

    // Property used to store the callback of the event handler to unsubscribe to it when leaving this page
    public unregisterBackButtonAction: any;

    constructor(...) { ... }

    ionViewDidEnter() {
        this.initializeBackButtonCustomHandler();
    }

    ionViewWillLeave() {
        // Unregister the custom back button action for this page
        this.unregisterBackButtonAction && this.unregisterBackButtonAction();
    }

    public initializeBackButtonCustomHandler(): void {
        this.unregisterBackButtonAction = this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
            this.customHandleBackButton();
        }, 10);
    }

    private customHandleBackButton(): void {
        // do what you need to do here ...
    }
}
```

So as you can see, the key is to store the callback of the `registerBackButtonAction` method and use it later when leaving the page (or when you want to restore the default behavior):

```
this.unregisterBackButtonAction = this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
    this.customHandleBackButton();
}, 10);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try it ASAP