# Issue while handling back button event in ionic2 application with custom routes

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, angular2-routing, angular2-router

I've implemented back button code in my ionic 2 application as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41373774/how-to-handle-back-button-on-ionic-2). but it is not working as expected.

However i'm getting console.log() while back button tapped.

Below is my code for reference.

1) app.routes.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { Login } from '../pages/Login/Login';
import { Orders } from '../pages/Orders/Orders';
import { OrderDetails } from '../pages/Orders/OrderDetails';
import { AssignOrder } from '../pages/Orders/AssignOrder';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', redirectTo: '/Orders',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'Login',
        component: Login
    },
    {
        path: 'Orders',
        component: Orders
    },
    {
        path: 'OrderDetails/:orderid',
        component: OrderDetails
    },
    {
        path: 'AssignOrder',
        component: AssignOrder
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
export const routedComponents = [Login, Orders, OrderDetails, AssignOrder];
```

2) app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { App, Platform, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})

export class MyApp {

  constructor(app: App, platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      if (splashScreen) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          splashScreen.hide();
        }, 100);
      }
    });

    platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
      let nav = app.getActiveNav();
      console.log(nav);
      let activeView = nav.getActive();
      if (activeView != null) {
        console.log('activeView:' + activeView);
        if (nav.canGoBack()) {
          nav.pop();
        } else if (typeof activeView.instance.backButtonAction === 'function')
          activeView.instance.backButtonAction();
        else nav.parent.select(0); // goes to the first tab
      }
      else {
        console.log('activeView is null');
      }
    });
  }
}
```

3) Orders.ts

In Orders page, if i click back button it will call function in app.component.ts in which i'm getting "activeView" as undefined in `let activeView = nav.getActive();` line. So, i get "activeView is null" is printed in console.(as mentioned in first solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41373774/how-to-handle-back-button-on-ionic-2)). Please see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BnZ9.png) image.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Platform, AlertController, LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { User } from '../../models/User';
import { Order } from '../../models/Order';
import { UserService } from '../../providers/UserService';
import { OrderService } from '../../providers/OrderService';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-Orders',
  templateUrl: 'Orders.html'
  // providers: [UserService, OrderService],
})
export class Orders implements OnInit {
  orders: Order[];
  selectedOrder: Order;
  user: User;
  error: any;
  showFilter: boolean;
  Search: any;
  loading: any;

  constructor(public router: Router,
    public userService: UserService,
    public orderService: OrderService,
    public platform: Platform,
    public alertCtrl: AlertController,
    public loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {
    this.showFilter = false;
    this.Search = '';
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('User') == null) {
      this.router.navigate(['/Login']);
    }
    else {
      this.userService.user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('User'));
      this.getOrders();
    }
  }

  backButtonAction() {

  }
}
```

4) OrderDetails.ts

In OrderDetails page, if i click back button it will call function in OrderDetails.ts because i'm overriding method of app.component.ts by 
`this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(this.backButtonAction, 10);` (as mentioned in second solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41373774/how-to-handle-back-button-on-ionic-2)). I'm getting "backButtonAction called" in console log too. but it gives me error at `this.gotoOrders();` line. It can't find gotoOrders() function in 'this'. In debug window, i've expand 'this' and i can't see gotoOrders() function there.  Please see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8TMa.png) image.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Platform, AlertController, LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { User } from '../../models/User';
import { Order } from '../../models/Order';
import { UserService } from '../../providers/UserService';
import { OrderService } from '../../providers/OrderService';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-OrderDetails',
  templateUrl: 'OrderDetails.html'
})
export class OrderDetails implements OnInit {
  modal: any;
  @Input() order: Order;
  @Output() close = new EventEmitter();
  user: User;
  loading: any;
  isStaff = this.userService.user.Role == "STAFF";
  navigated = false; // true if navigated here

  constructor(public router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    public userService: UserService,
    public platform: Platform,
    public orderService: OrderService,
    public alertCtrl: AlertController,
    public loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {
    this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(this.backButtonAction, 10);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.userService.user == null) {
      this.userService.logout();
    }
    else {
      this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
        if (params['orderid'] !== undefined) {
          let orderid = params['orderid'];
          this.navigated = true;
        }
      });
    }
  }

  backButtonAction() {
    console.log('backButtonAction called');
    this.gotoOrders();
    // if (this.modal && this.modal.index === 0) {
    //   this.modal.dismiss();
    // } else {
    //   /* exits the app, since this is the main/first tab */
    //   this.platform.exitApp();
    //   // this.navCtrl.setRoot(AnotherPage);  <-- if you wanted to go to another page
    // }
  }

  gotoOrders(): void {
    this.router.navigate(['/Orders']);
  }
}
```

Comment: Ionic 2 uses [Navcontroller](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/) not angular router..

Comment: But router is working fine. Only issue is detecting routes and functiond during back button press event.

Comment: never tried it.. however if you are using router then maybe even the backbutton should use router instead of nav as the linked posts suggest...maybe you should look for angular2 sol

Comment: `this.navCtrl.setRoot(AnotherPage)` is nav controller instead of router

Comment: I'm already using Angular2.

Comment: i meant angular router based solution..sorry for confusion

Comment: That's what i was asking for. :)

Comment: ionic 2 uses angular 2 this is very redundant

Comment: Finally, I've change my all code to work with NavController instead of router and all working fine.