# How to write custom action for ionic back button.? where Custom back button located ??

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, angular2-template, angular2-forms

The below action i want to perform
on click of back button existing price in previous page has to update with new value which will be send along with back button.

please help to get soltution i am new to ionic

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ionic override all BACK button behaviour for specific controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32231737/ionic-override-all-back-button-behaviour-for-specific-controller)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle back button on Ionic 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41373774/how-to-handle-back-button-on-ionic-2)