# Ionic model is not dismiss on browser back button

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am working on ionic project , where I have used an ionic model ,

My model is dismissed on clicking anywhere on windows but

when **I press browser back button model doesn't dismiss and stay there .**

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to what one might expect, this is not currently a feature of the Ionic 3 modal. The feature request is [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-v3/issues/563), please upvote it!

A possible solution is to intercept the hardware back button using the Platform plugin, e.g. `platform.registerBackButtonAction()` and run your own code. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41373774/how-to-handle-back-button-on-ionic-2).